# How to upgrade to Java 11 without modules?

Tags: java, java-11, java-module

When I try to build my project with Maven 3.5.4 and Java 11.0.2, the build fails with the message:

> Compilation failure: Compilation failure: [ERROR]
>   xx/directory/krb5/KerberosContextSource.java:[38,20] package
>   sun.security.krb5 is not visible [ERROR]   (package sun.security.krb5
>   is declared in module java.security.jgss, which does not export it to
>   the unnamed module)

I have read from several sources that [it's not necessary to modularise your project to upgrade it to Java 9+](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/from-java-8-to-java-11.html).

Why do I still run into this issue which clearly asks me to define a module-info.java? As mentioned [here](https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-your-project-to-jigsaw-step-by-step).

How do I get around it?

Comment: The issue here is that you are trying to make use of unsupported/undocumented classes in the java.security.jgss module. It's nothing to do with whether your code is in a module or not. You can workaround it temporarily by compiling/running with `--add-exports java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED` but the real solution is to stop relying on JDK internal classes.

Comment: @AlanBateman If so, how do I find the right replacement for it? Could you point me to it?

Comment: The classes in sun.security.krb5 were never a supported/documented interface. The supported API for Kerbose is defined in the java.security.jgss and org.ietf.jgss packages.

Comment: @AlanBateman Do you mean to say instead of directly accessing for eg. KrbException which I see under java.security.jgss.sun.security.krb5.KrbException, I should be accessing it via an API defined in java.security.jgss and/or org.ietf.jgss? If so, could you tell me the right API for this example. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.